# Clojure: how to conj to front of hash map in swap! function

Tags: clojure

This works ok, except it adds the new value to the *end* of the hash map:

`(swap! my-atom conj @new-fields)`

I need for `my-atom` to be the *first* item in @new-fields.  I have tried `assoc-in`, `cons` and pretty much everything that might "put things together".  What can I do to `swap!` in `my-atom` to the front of `@new-fields`?

Comment: Hashmaps are unordered so there's no such thing as the 'end'.

Comment: The data consistently appears in the same order when rendered (cljs) and `conj`-ing consistently puts the `new-atom` value at the end, so while I understand what you're saying, it doesn't preclude the possibility that the the atom can be added as the first value in the hash map.  At least I hope not.

Comment: Keys only keep insertion order for a small number of items. Once you go past a certain size (8,  perhaps?) then the order changes a lot. But you can't even rely on that as the implementation could change in another version of Clojure. There are no order guarantees on maps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hash-maps are unordered collections; logically they do not *have* a "beginning" *or* an "end". They have an iteration order, which is an implementation detail (based on the hashes of the keys) and which users should not rely upon. This iteration order will be consistent between readings of the same map because the map is an immutable value.

It sounds like you want a different datatype, to provide predictable ordering. *Sorted maps* are the easiest replacement. You can create them using [`sorted-map`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/sorted-map) (which sorts using `compare` on the keys), or `sorted-map-by` (which takes a comparator function to compare keys with). `conj`ing a key-value pair into one will put it first iff the new key is lowest according to the comparator.
Note that these are still logical maps: If the comparator says two keys equal one another then they are the same key and the resulting map will only have one value for them.

If you can't make that fit your requirements, it sounds like you're not actually using a logical map, since the values have both an index *and* a key. A few alternatives if you really need to manually set the order might be

- A vector of `[key value]` tuples or maps with a single key/value pair.
- A map with composite keys `[index old-key]`, sorted on `index`, where `old-key` is whatever keys you're using now.