# Are maps in Clojure ordered?

Tags: python, clojure

I'm coming from Python where maps (i.e. dicts) are not ordered by default. Starting to learn Clojure and I came across this:

```
(def point {:x 5 :y 7})
=> #'user/point
point
=> {:x 5, :y 7}
(let [{:keys [x y]} point]
  (println "x:" x "y:" y))
x: 5 y: 7
```

It seems to me that for this destructuring to work one would have to rely on the map being ordered (and of course, remembering the order). Is that true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Clojure maps are not ordered, although there is a such thing as a `sorted-map`.  You are getting a consistent order because you are using the keys to access the values.  See what happens when you change the key names...

```
user=> point
{:a 5, :b 7}

user=> (let [{:keys [x y]} point]
  #_=>   (println "x:" x "y:" y))
x: nil y: nil
nil

user=> (let [{:keys [a b]} point]
  #_=>   (println "a:" a "b:" b))
a: 5 b: 7
```

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33042116/clojure-how-to-conj-to-front-of-hash-map-in-swap-function) that has an accepted answer that is relevant to your question.

Comment: Oh! Thanks, I didn't realize the actual keys were being used as parameters. That makes me feel better about  it. lol

Answer (score 14):

Clojure has three built-in map types: array maps, hash maps and sorted maps.

Of these, hash maps and sorted maps are unordered, but array maps actually are ordered: this is explained in [the data structures section](http://clojure.org/data_structures#Data%20Structures-ArrayMaps) of the official documentation on [clojure.org](http://clojure.org).

It is important to note, however, that array maps are mostly used for performance reasons – small map literals (≤ 8 entries) are compiled to array maps instead of hash maps and `assoc`ing new keys on to an array map will return a hash map if it causes it to cross the size threshold. One can construct bigger array maps by explicitly calling `clojure.core/array-map`, but array map operations are O(n), and thus become rather slow in the presence of too many entries, so this is not a universal ordered map data structure.

If you need an ordered map capable of delivering good performance regardless of size, you should use Alan Malloy's / Flatland's [ordered](https://github.com/clj-commons/ordered) instead – it provides persistent ordered sets and maps backed backed by built-in data structures (a set or a map + a vector to keep track of insertion order).

Comment: The link to **ordered** points to an old version. This is newer https://github.com/amalloy/ordered

Comment: Does it described somewhere in the docs that Clojure uses array-map type for small maps (≤ 8 entries)? Just interesting, how you get this number. Or you got it experimentally?