# From a Map, how do I group the sequences' elements (values) by order?

Tags: clojure, etl

I have a map that represents a database. The keys are fields, the values are transactions. The order of the values matter; the first elements are a transaction, the second elements are a second transaction, etc.

```
{"a" (72144305 72144777 72145239),
 "b" (110.5 200.0 50.0),
 "c" (10.0 0.0 5.0),
 "d" (20.2 30.0 15.0),
 "e" ("control" "test" "unmanaged")}
```

I want to transform it to a list of transactions.

```
[(72144305 110.5 10.0 20.2 "control"), (72144777 200.0 0.0 30.0 "test"), (72145239 50.0 5.0 15.0 "unmanaged")]
```

In other words, take the first element of each value and put it in a sequence, then take the 2nd element of each value, put them in a sequence, and do the same with the last element in the values.

What I've tried:

I've tried solving it recursively

```
(defn get-transactions
  ([m]
   (let [data (vals m)]
     (if (nil? (rest m))
       (map first data)
       (get-transactions (map rest data))))))
```

and I've thought about using `(map #(nth % 0) (vals data)` to extract a single element and then mapping that over the `(vals data)`, but haven't been able to figure out the exact syntax.

With the recursive solution, I can't figure out how to pass back a map with `(map first data)` removed. It currently gives a the errors:

> Execution error (ClassCastException) at java.lang.Object/toString (Object.java:162).
> clojure.lang.LazySeq incompatible with java.util.Map$Entry

EDIT: I have an almost working solution. The input is `(vals m)`.

```
(defn get-transactions
  "Call on vals m"
  ([data]
   (if (= 1 (count (first data)))
     (map first data)
     (vec (conj (get-transactions (map rest data)) (map first data))))))
```

For some reason it doesn't group correctly. Sample output

```
[(72144777 200.0 0.0 30.0 "test") 72145239 50.0 5.0 15.0 "unmanaged (72144305 110.5 10.0 20.2 "control")]
```

The issue is the middle transaction is not in a seq.

Comment: Be careful with just using `vals` here; only literal/small maps are ordered; if you want this to work with any map, and you always want to have `"a"` in first place, you have to take care for that as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Matrix transposition in clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347315/matrix-transposition-in-clojure)

Comment: @cfrick That does answer it. How do I mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Clojure hash-maps aren't ordered by default, so you shouldn't rely on that order of the entries.

Small maps are ordered, as they use array-map type instead of hash-map type, a threshold is 8 entries (I suggest you to read [Are maps in Clojure ordered?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401121/are-maps-in-clojure-ordered)), but if you expect your map to get bigger, you have to take care of that and maybe use a different data structure.

That said, if you want to return exactly vector with seqs, you can do:

```
(def data '{"a" (72144305 72144777 72145239),
            "b" (110.5 200.0 50.0),
            "c" (10.0 0.0 5.0),
            "d" (20.2 30.0 15.0),
            "e" ("control" "test" "unmanaged")})

(defn get-transactions [data]
  (if (seq (first data))
    (conj (get-transactions (map rest data))
          (map first data))
    []))

(get-transactions (vals data))
=> [(72145239 50.0 5.0 15.0 "unmanaged") (72144777 200.0 0.0 30.0 "test") (72144305 110.5 10.0 20.2 "control")]
```

Or even shorter:

```
(apply mapv list (vals data))
```

If you want to return a sequence of vectors (or sequence of sequences), you can also do:

```
(defn get-transactions [data]
  (when (seq (first data))
    (cons (mapv first data)
          (get-transactions (mapv rest data)))))
```

Comment: You talk about solving the unordered problem with a different data structure, but I don't see how that's necessary here. The easy solution is to just specify the field order: `(defn transpose [by-field] (apply mapv vector (map by-field ["a" "b" "c" "d" "e"])))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a [utility I wrote for working with CSV data](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/23.03.04/api/tupelo.csv).

Your data is in a "column matrix" (aka attribute matrix), where each "column" in a table is an individual attribute `a`, `b`, etc.  That is, you have a map from attribute name to a sequence of values for that attribute.

The other way to represent the data is to have a sequence of "entities", each of which is a map from attribute name to a single value for that entity.

To convert from an attribute map to a sequence of entities just do:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.csv :as csv]
    ))

(def data
  '{"a" (72144305 72144777 72145239),
    "b" (110.5 200.0 50.0),
    "c" (10.0 0.0 5.0),
    "d" (20.2 30.0 15.0),
    "e" ("control" "test" "unmanaged")})

(verify
  (is= (csv/attrs->entities data)
    [{"a" 72144305, "b" 110.5, "c" 10.0, "d" 20.2, "e" "control"}
     {"a" 72144777, "b" 200.0, "c" 0.0, "d" 30.0, "e" "test"}
     {"a" 72145239, "b" 50.0, "c" 5.0, "d" 15.0, "e" "unmanaged"}]))
```

Build using [my favorite template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template).  You may also be interested in a related entity for [more general 2-D array processing](https://cljdoc.org/d/tupelo/tupelo/23.03.04/api/tupelo.array) in Clojure.  The main version uses normal immutable Clojure vectors. A 2nd namespace uses mutable Java arrays for speed (only when required!).